# How can I access the global object in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global

I've tried to type `global` and `Global` in the browser. Both result in an *"ReferenceError: undefined variable"*.

I know that browser's `window` is an alias for the global object. I also know, that Node.js' `global`is the same in server-side JavaScript.

`global` seems to be inaccessible in the browser and `window` seems inaccessible in Node.js. Is there a standard way to access the global scope that would work in both environments?

Comment: `var globalEverywhere = window || global;`

Comment: To be specific, `window` is not an alias for the global object. It **is** the global object.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, the web browser's global object is `window` and for now this won't change anytime soon.

If you need to alias `global`, you can use immediately-invoked function expressions ([IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)):

```
(function(global) {
    // Here global will always be the global object
})(window || global);
```

Comment: @zerkms I've added the IIFE thing, btw try to look for *self-invoked functions* in Google and you're going to check that both refer to the same concept......

Comment: @zerkms Is there any naming standard where I can find that it must be called IIFE?

Comment: @zerkms I've edited it, BTW, I find that your behavior isn't the expected one in SO and I don't care you're over 100k reputation. The answer is correct even using one or other term, and AFAIK, IIFE is just another way of naming the same thing... Maybe you can provide a link to convince me and show me how wrong I was to receive a downvote for this ;)

Comment: @zerkms In fact, if you use google you'll find a lot of people saying "IIFE or self-invoked anonymous functions or self-invoked functions"............. to explain what's behind the whole term.......

Comment: I think the order should be `window || global`. As it is, this doesn't protect against 3rd party libraries declaring a variable called `global`. All that will happen is that your code will use the 3rd party `global` in the browser instead of `window`

Comment: @slebetman You're right, I've edited my answer to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (typeof window != undefined) {
    global = window;
}
```

Or:

```
var global = global || window;
```

And access it with *global* in both Node.js and the browser.

Comment: I wouldn't go this way because there's a high risk that some other library would overwrite `global` variable...

Comment: @zerkms wrong, the nearest variable declaration would win, so the IIFE (happy?) would win, so I don't see the issue. Ok, maybe in the global scope, `global` could be overwritten, yes, but BTW I find that the IIFE (happy again? haha) a better practice!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer "wrong, the nearest variable declaration would win" --- http://jsfiddle.net/cgmx5rL8/ http://jsfiddle.net/j8ddyjtk/ --- I literally don't see any difference in behaviour. Both solutions return the equal but wrong result.

Comment: @zerkms you can use `this` there is no way to overwrite `this`. http://jsfiddle.net/j8ddyjtk/1/

Comment: @zerkms probably the best would be `(function(global) { })(this);`

Comment: @jcubic that's error prone - you should not rely on that (because of `'use strict';` and bundlers like webpack)

Comment: @jcubic: In ES6 (most modern browsers) `this` is not allowed to refer to the global object in strict mode. It is a solution if you write non-strict mode code. Just be sure you don't have a global "use strict" at the top of the file.

Comment: @zerkms about the nearest variable, I fail to add the comment here. it was for my own answer...

Comment: What do you mean by "windows"? [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) the operating system? Or the web browser (the browser windows)? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen sorry it was 7 years ago I don't remember. Probably it was supposed to be a browser.